# How to Obtain DNN User Profile Fields and Values in Custom Module?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I'm developing a custom DNN module that needs to gather sensitive information from users for a payment gateway onboarding process.  We want to leverage the DNN User Profile module and create additional required fields.  I've located DotnetNuke.Entities.Users.UserProfile as well as DotNetNuke.Security.Profile.ProfileProvder.GetUserProfile(UserInfo).  Which namespace is our best option to read the user profile values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read profile data like this

```
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Profile;

ProfilePropertyDefinition ppd = UserInfo.Profile.GetProperty("FirstName");
string FirstName = ppd.PropertyValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Profile;


 UserInfo oUserInfo = UserController.GetUserById(PortalSettings.PortalId, iUserID);
 string sCustomProperty = oUserInfo.Profile.GetPropertyValue("customproperty");
```